# Почему не округляются числа в PHP?

Tags: php

Почему при преобразования вещественного числа в целое число в PHP, оно не окгругляется ?
Например:

```
<?php
$number_1 = 1.800;
$number_2 = intval($number_1);
echo $number_2;
?>
```

Код выводит 1

Comment: Встречный вопрос: а почему оно должно округляться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В PHP для округления чисел применяются следующие функции:

- round – округление до ближайшего значения;
- ceil – округление до ближайшего значения в большую сторону;
- floor – округление до ближайшего значения в меньшую сторону.

intval — Возвращает целое значение переменной

Answer (score 0):

> When converting from float to int, the number will be rounded *towards zero*.

Работает ровно так, [как задокументировано](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)